$L^p$ spaces and $L^2$
I am stuck in an exercise:
"Establish for which $p\in [1,\infty]$ the function  belongs to $L^p(\mathbb{R})$"
$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{|x|}}$$
Solution:
$$|f(x)|^p=\bigg(\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{|x|}}\bigg)^p$$
the function is integrable at $+\infty$ for each $p\in [1,\infty)$, near $0$, for $\frac p 2<1$, so $p<2$, therefore $1\leq p \lt 2.$
Now I'm not able to figure it out, what is the procedure to follow in order to arrive at the statement of the solution? Unfortunately, the book doesn't do the entire calculation.
Secondly how to verify that:
"the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}\in \thinspace L^1, \thinspace \notin L^2$"

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

you have to study the behaviour near $0$ and at $\infty$, what's not clear? How the author of the book found the values of $p$?

Please remove your final additional question. Ask it in a separate post. As for the firdt question, be more specific about what you do/don't  understand in the solution. This will help answerers to provide an appropriate explanation, without wasting their time and yours about details which are clear to you.

We say that $f\in L^p(\Omega)$ if $\int_{\Omega}|f|^pdx<\infty$, in your case you have to study the convergence of
$$\int_{\Bbb R} \left(\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{|x|}}\right)^p dx $$
Note that as $|x|\to \infty$ you don't have problems since the fast decaying of $e^{-x^2}$ (so you have convergence for all $p\ge 1$). Near $x=0$, recall that
$$\int_0^1 \frac1{x^a}dx<\infty  \iff a<1$$
Since the term with the exponential is continuous, the integral converges if
$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{|x|^{p/2}}dx $ converges, namely $p/2<1$.

thanks, it is clear, can I ask you how can you assume $p/2<1$? Is there a rule/theorem or it derives from the fact that is easy to note that for $p/2>1, \thinspace x\in[0,1]$ doesn't converge.. I'm asking because ok,  now I'm using softwares to check what I need, but just in case It wouldn't be possible to use electronic devices it is a bit challenging to have this intuition

The undetermined integral $\int{1/{x^a}}dx$ has simple analytical solutions for any $a$ and positive $x$, with $a=1$ being a special case. You can plug in those solutions into the determined integral $\int_r^1{1/{x^a}}dx$ and let $r$ go to $0$ from above. That directly leads to the result used by the answer above.

@MatteoX this is a basic fact of improper integrals, see for example this answer or any analysis book

@SineoftheTime thank you very much for the link I'm checking it asap

As the function is even it suffices to study $\int\limits_0^\infty x^{-p/2}e^{-px^2}\,dx.$ For $x\ge 1$ we have $$0<x^{-p/2}e^{-px^2}\le e^{-x},\ \int\limits_1^\infty e^{-x}\,dx=e^{-1}$$ For $0<x\le 1$ there holds $$ e^{-p}x^{-p/2}\le x^{-p/2}e^{-px^2}\le x^{-p/2}$$ Hence the convergence on $(0,1]$ is equivalent to the convergence of $\int_0^1x^{-p/2}\,dx,$ i.e. $p<2.$
